# Android : getting data from cursor

Tags: java, android, listview, cursor

After running a query. `Cursor` have result like this(I am only giving 4 here)

```
ID | Name | Topic|
------------------
1  | A    | Poster
------------------
1 | B     | Poster
------------------
2 | C      | Presentation
-------------------------
2 | D      | Presentation
```

Now, All I want to show `A & B` and `C & D`  on a same cell in listview. How can I do that?

is there any way to get data like this way.

Comment: Where do you get the Data, from SQLITE?

Answer (score 1):

you can just get the data from the cursor as strings and merge them as you like before you save them in the listview.

`String example = (cursor.getString(0) + "," + cursor.getString(1)); 
    cursor.moveToPosition(id);

    example = example + (cursor.getString(0) + "," + cursor.getString(1));

    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    listItems.add(example);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code it is working for me.

```
c.moveToFirst();
        if (c != null) {
            do {
                for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) {

                    Log.e("", "" + c.getString(i));
                }
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a bean for listitem object that will contain same type of items then develop a custom listview adaptor for that item in order to archive that goal.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY Topic in your SQL query and join A, B manually. I don't think you can use the cursor directly